# Tier prices does not work properly (nopcommerce)

Tags: c#, e-commerce, nopcommerce

I have nopcommerce application and 3 type of price. Also I have my custom roles (Dealer, wholesale). Please see the picture below

[image]

Every product variant also has 2 type of price

[image]

**The problem is** when I log in under user that has Dealer role price doesn't change. And when 
I log in under wholesale role I also see the same price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I needed to add additional flag on productvariant --> HasTierPrices -- true or 1